# Eclipse debugger suspends on every republish

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I'm working on a web project in Eclipse Juno.  It's deployed on a Websphere 7.0 server using the IBM plugin.  Recently I have started having a problem where every time I republish to the server, triggered either automatically on saving or manually, the debugger suspends and opens the J9VMInternals class.  It's quite annoying and I'd love to make it stop.  There is not visibly a breakpoint set in that class.

I had this problem a while back while using MyEclipse but it had stopped when I made the switch to Juno, only returning recently.  I have not made any big changes to the environment, although do tweak settings here and there so it's possible I triggered something unknowingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to resolve that by disabling

```
Suspend execution on uncaught exception
```

Under

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Debug
```

I had a similar issue with `tomcat` and some jdk threading class (I cant remember witch one) and could resolve like that.

**EDIT**

The class mentioned above is `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`

Comment: Tried this, no luck.  Thanks for the idea though